# Decimal stored in database returned to .net Profile as rounded decimal

Tags: vb.net, decimal, asp.net-membership, string-formatting

I have a custom .net profile which stores a decimal value in an SQL Table

```
Column decCode = Numeric (3,1)
```

The value stored is `0.8`

My profile property in web.config is

```
<add name="decCode" provider="SqlProfile" customProviderData="decCode,Decimal" type="System.Decimal" />
```

When I execute a `ProfileBase.GetPropertyValue("decCode")` the value always seems to be rounded up. (ProfileBase is not inherited, its the standard aspnet profile class)

As an example :
(in DB as 0.8)

```
Dim dec As Decimal = CType(pc.GetPropertyValue("decCode"), Decimal) === 1D
Dim a1 As String = String.Format("{0}: {1}", "G", dec.ToString("G")) === 1
Dim a2 As String = String.Format("{0}: {1}", "C", dec.ToString("C")) === £1.00
Dim a3 As String = String.Format("{0}: {1}", "E04", dec.ToString("E04")) === 1.0000E+000
Dim a4 As String = String.Format("{0}: {1}", "F", dec.ToString("F")) === 1.00
Dim a5 As String = String.Format("{0}: {1}", "N", dec.ToString("N")) === 1.00
Dim a6 As String = String.Format("{0}: {1}", "P", dec.ToString("P")) === 100.00%
Dim a7 As String = dec.ToString() === 1
Dim a8 As String = dec.ToString("0.0") === 1.0
```

Where as if I get the value of decCode using linq

```
return (_context.pUserProfiles.Where(p => p.UserId == GUID).FirstOrDefault().decCode).ToString()
```

i get 0.8

how can I use the `ProfileBase.GetPropertyValue` to return me the correct decimal?

Comment: Try use DOUBLE instead DECIMAL in CType().

Comment: Tried `Dim dec As Double = CType(pc.GetPropertyValue("decCode"), Double)` === showing as 1.0

Comment: Did you update the customProviderData also to double?

Comment: excellent, that appears to have worked, can you put this as an answer and I can upvote and accept, thanks

Comment: You're pretty welcome. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must change the DECIMAL to DOUBLE in "customProviderData" and the "cType", as follows:

```
 <add name="decCode" provider="SqlProfile" customProviderData="decCode,Double" type="System.Double" />
```

and

```
  Dim dec As Double = CType(pc.GetPropertyValue("decCode"), Double)
```